# Conditional Stroke Rectangle WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to give a rectangle a stroke / border if a certain condition is true. Unfortunately, I am unable to acheive this after googling for hours. I do know that I can set the Stroke property on the rectangle and even bind the color. However, I want the rectangle to only have a stroke based on a boolean. You will find my code below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Squares}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Height="{Binding Height,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Fill="{Binding Color}">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding GalleryX, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Y="{Binding GalleryY, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}"/>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

I tried to use DataTemplate.Triggers for example. While the following lines do compile, their not the solution.

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="{Binding Width,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Height="{Binding Height,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Fill="{Binding Color}">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding GalleryX, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Y="{Binding GalleryY, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}"/>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisited}">
                            <Setter TargetName="rect" Property="Stroke" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
```

I hope you can help me to find a solution. I want to have a black stroke on each rectangle in the itemsControl if the IsVisited property is true.

Comment: Does IsVisited fire a change notification, i.e. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a DataTrigger `Value` like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisited}" Value="True">
```

Comment: I just did, but does not make a difference

Comment: do the other Bindings works ? I tested it my computer and you must add the Value property.

Comment: they do. I tested the stroke without binding as well!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to `oz shalom`. I went with the following format:

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Height="{Binding Height,  Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Fill="{Binding Color}">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding GalleryX, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}" Y="{Binding GalleryY, Converter={StaticResource PositionConverter}}"/>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisited}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Rectangle.Style>
                    </Rectangle>
                </DataTemplate>
```

The previous format in my question post works as well. The problem was that I forgot to `RaisePropertyChanged()` for the binded IsVisted property.